# DevExpress MVC controls generating 2mb of javascript per page load

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, onload

We've started using the DevExpress MVC controls, which requires this code added in our Site.Master:

```
<% Html.DevExpress().RenderScripts(Page,
       new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView },
       new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.HtmlEditor },
       new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Editors },
       new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout },
       new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Chart },
       new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Report }
 ); %>
```

But this renders a massive 2mb javascript file through a handler called DXR.axd. When using Firefox this javascript is too large and increases the page's onload time from ~500 ms to ~5,000 ms (I timed it before and after).

Using Chrome it loads in ~750ms

This is a severe performance hit and causes a very noticeable pause when the page is rendering.  Firefox reports that the DOMContentLoaded event takes 5 seconds to fire (because it takes so long to load and parse that 2mb of javascript)

What can I do to fix this problem?

I note that their own site http://mvc.devexpress.com has the exact same problem: if you view source and look for "DXR.axd" then download that file it is even bigger, at 2.6mb, and they also have a very slow onload in Firefox

Answer (score 2):

I suppose they create a dynamic js file instead of using static js file just to avoide people might copy their js files. However there are other controls on the market without this problem. If you need a specific control that you can find just there...well you have to survive wuth this problem...otherwise change for another control suite. However, consider that more the controls are "out of the box" and ready fo the use with just a few code to be written, more your performance...go down, because each control takes with it several feature that you actually dont need.

Comment: Agree with your last sentence, I just feel that DevEx team made a bad design decision by porting their Asp.Net controls to MVC, so they have many drawbacks like this one. I managed to refactor it to gain some performance, but I just feel that this will be the last time using them for Asp.Net MVC app.(by saying that, they do have best Winforms controls out there :)

Comment: @MiBu thanks for adding a bounty :) can you add an answer detailing what you did to refactor it and gain performance?

Comment: Francesco, if that was their intention it doesnt work, I was able to easily view the js with a simple "view source"

Comment: However the Js code generated is not always the same and dpends on the settings of the controls, so also if one copy it it cannot be reused in a generic page. 
Another reason they do that is making the use of controls easier, since the programmer doesnt need to add header js files, since they are automatically created including just the one needed for the controls that are on the page.
The last technique, is an actually poor design choice and has a lot of drawbck. It is an old technique...that now is well known to be inadequate.

Comment: I only use reports, so I removed all unnecessary scripts and stylesheets(time load is drastically improved and since it's specialized app for about 500 users, I'll live with it), and placed them on my report view. The more I reflect on it, the more it seems they missed the point, just to get reporting working you need to reference 15 libraries, which end up being bigger than the rest of my app.

Comment: You don't have to reference 15 libraries unless your report uses charts, bar codes, graphics, images, and every other control they produce. If it's plain vanilla report, at most will be 5. Did you contact their support about the size? They might tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: The more controls you are referencing, the bigger the js file. Doyou really need all those controls in the same page?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to fix it, but I have been working with DX components for more than a year in my current project so just want to tell you one thing: it's 3rd party component so you have to live with it, no other way. The components in my project also generate tons of scripts, and I personally think that you should only use it to solve a specific problem (pivotgrid in our case), and poor performance is a trade-off. I myself found several bugs in their components, some of them are low level implementation and they cannot fix it willy-nilly, at least for now.